# Display a gridview with content from an api oncreate

Tags: java, android, gridview

I want to display set the content of gridview to be as gotten from an api.
I used Ion to call in my api and saved them into a generic list of a class i.e(List list;) i used picasso to load images from a url but when set the gridviews adapter in the oncreate it doesn't show the items in the gridview when the app comes up, but when I minimise and bring it back the contents show. I need help making sure it's contents loads up with the app.

Comment: Do you have a problem with this code? Your question should be much more specific.

Comment: I have a problem setting the adapter for the gridview so the contents of the gridview lads on start of the app